# Excel VBA SaveAS only one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel with multiple sheets and I try to save each sheet except 4 using vba.
The thing is if I try any other format than .csv it saves the whole excel making the sheet to be saved the active one.

This is the code I'm using(the one with csv):

```
Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim xDir As String
Dim folder As FileDialog
Set folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If folder.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xDir = folder.SelectedItems(1)
For Each s In Worksheets
    If s.Name <> "Template" And s.Name <> "Interface" And s.Name <> "Accounts" And s.Name <> "Instr" Then
        s.SaveAs xDir & "\" & s.Name, xlCSV
    End If
Next
For Each s In Worksheets
    If s.Name <> "Template" And s.Name <> "Interface" And s.Name <> "Accounts" And s.Name <> "Instr" Then
        s.Delete
    End If
Next s
End Sub
```

I want to save it as xlsm so it will keep all the formatting I have in the master excel.(auto fit on columns and all borders).

I've got no idea what's wrong with it...

Comment: Yeah I think `Worksheet.SaveAs` has this behavior. One workaround is to `Copy` the worksheet (creates a new workbook) and then save the `ActiveWorkbook`. Note that if you just want the formatting preserved, you can use `xlsx` and not `xlsm`.

Comment: CSV files have only one sheet.  If you load something with multiple sheets, they will get removed as well as any formatting, due to the file type.  The .xl* file types will save entire workbooks.  You can `Sheets.Move` [for one sheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.move) and `.SaveAs` the new workbook, not saving anything with the old workbook.  You could also `Sheets.Copy`, as BigBen stated.

Comment: @Cyril Cool, sheets.move worked awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Cyril, I switched to `Sheets.Move` and everything works now.
Thanks.